# In Ember.js does setupController and model hooks work only for dynamic segments?

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to understand the `setupController` and `model` hooks, will they be invoked only in case of dynamic segments?

This is my router configuration, I see the application is working fine,but I do not see these hooks getting executed:

```
// Router, this need to connect view and controller
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource("login", {path : "/"});
  this.resource("home" , {path : "home/:home_id"});
});

App.Router.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController:function(controller,model){
    console.log("in setupController hook for index route");
  }
});

App.Router.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController:function(controller,model){
    console.log("in setupController hook for login route");
  }
});

App.Router.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController:function(controller,model){
    console.log("in setupController hook for login route");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest ember (1.0.0-RC.1) You should define your routes like this:

```
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
});
```

They are part of your `App`, and don't have the `Router` part.

[Working JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/249/edit)

As a note on `model` and `setupController` hook behavior:

In a route, `model` will only be called when navigating directly to a URL containing a dynamic segment. The parameters passed into `model` are used to retrieve the model for that route using the dynamic segment.

If the route is reached using a `{{#linkTo route myObject}}` or `transitionTo(myObject)` call then the passed object is used to call `setupController` directly and `model` is not called.

The `setupController` hook will be called every time the route enters the

[Ember API docs for `model`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model)

[Ember API docs for `setupController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController)