# Can't get controller properties and bindings to work properly in Ember - pulling my hair out

Tags: javascript, data-binding, ember.js

Good morning,

I would appreciate any help you can provide.  I'm currently pulling my hair out in frustration.  I really want to get the hang of Ember but I must be missing something.

All I want to do is the following:

1. User visits `/rooms` route, app does a `App.Room.find()` call
2. User visits `/rooms/1` route, app sets a `selectedRoom` property on the `RoomController`.
3. Use the `selectedRoom` property in the `rooms` template to indicate which room is currently selected.
4. Create an `isSelected` computed property using the `selectedRoom` property in each `RoomController` to adjust the display of that particular room

This should be easy, but it is not working for me.

**Routes**

```
App.RoomsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: ->
    @controllerFor('application').set('currentRoute', 'rooms') 
  model: ->
    App.Room.find()

App.RoomRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (model) ->
    @controllerFor('application').set('currentRoute', 'rooms') 
    @controllerFor('rooms').set('selectedRoom', model) 
  model: ->
    App.Room.find(params.room_id)
```

**Controller**

*(this should set a default value so that when the user is only at `/rooms`, there is a string to write to the template)*

```
App.RoomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  selectedRoom: 'default'

App.RoomController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['rooms']
  isSelected: ( ->
    selectedRoom = 'controllers.rooms.selectedRoom'
    if selectedRoom.id == @get('id')
      return true
    else
      return false
  ).property('controllers.rooms.selectedRoom')
```

**Template**

*rooms*

```
<p>My selected room: {{ selectedRoom.room_id }}</p>

{{#each room in controller}}
  {{#linkTo 'rooms.room' room}} Room {{ room.room_id }} {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

*room*

```
# This template is a contrived simplification of what I want to do... but essentially I just want to be able to access the `isSelected` property of the `RoomController`
<div {{ bindAttr class='isSelected' }}>
  <p>Room {{ room.room_name }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code (with some blanks filled in) on an older version of Ember (v1.0.0-pre.4), it seemed to work as you wanted, with a selected room becoming highlighted when you clicked on it.

When I tried it with the latest version (1.0.0-rc.4) it wasn't working, so this tells me it's probably a breaking change in Ember to blame.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570270/in-ember-js-does-setupcontroller-and-model-hooks-work-only-for-dynamic-segments#15570807), the `model` and `setupController` hooks are called under different circumstances.

To make your code work, I had to add `controller.set("model", model);` in `setupController`:

```
App.RoomsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('application').set('currentRoute', 'rooms');
    // Load the model property here because the model hook isn't 
    // called in this case
    controller.set("model", model);
  },
  model: function() {
    return App.Room.find();
  }
});`
```

Not an Ember expert, and not sure if this is the same problem you were having, but this works for me. The full working code I tried is here: https://gist.github.com/jasonschock/5667656#file-app-js-L15

Comment: You could also call `this._super(controller, model)` in `setupController` to the same effect.

Comment: I'll give this a try tonight - thanks for the response. I've been fiddling around with it (including changes to how I call `setupController` and `model`) and was still not working for me.  I'll compare to your working code.

Comment: UGH.  I was missing an "s" on one of my controller names.  THanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I don't personally love that Ember wants you to have both RoomController and RoomsController. Readability suffers a bit.