# Lazy loading in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

i am attempting to implement lazy loading pagination. i have a model that represents a 'page' in the paginated view. it contains an array of paginated objects plus a nested set of other 'pages'. (see https://gist.github.com/hooverlunch/6314207) i don't want to load in the array of objects for the other pages only after their links are clicked.

but it seems the route's model method fires only once, when the page is first loaded.

is there any way to make it fire each time a relevant link is clicked? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: as a matter of fact, now i'm downright confused as to why the model method is not firing on each link click....

Comment: oh wait, now i get it. no need to load the model if it has it already. but then what should i do? perhaps a transition event on the route?

Answer (score 0):

Model hook gets called when you visit a route directly via url but not when you use linkTo helper or pass context via transitionTo. If you need something to be called in those cases, use the route's setupController hook instead.

See [In Ember.js does setupController and model hooks work only for dynamic segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570270/in-ember-js-does-setupcontroller-and-model-hooks-work-only-for-dynamic-segments)

Answer (score 0):

Create an action

```
<button {{action 'goToPage' pageObj}}>{{pageObj.id}}</button>
```

in your route add

```
 Myember.KbGlyprobsPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    goToPage: function(pageObj){
      var newPage = Myember.KbGlyprobPage.find(pageObj.id);
      this.transitionTo('Page', newPage);
    }
  }
 });
```