# Ember setupController not called on transitionTo for dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js, routes

How to get the setupController to run when transition into to a dynamic segment?

The model updates but the values initialized in the setupController are not updated because the setupController is not called.

Here is a ember-twiddle example of the setupController not being called.

https://ember-twiddle.com/897695ac7d18a76fede8f0fb7c9daa44?openFiles=routes.dummy.js%2CC

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570270/in-ember-js-does-setupcontroller-and-model-hooks-work-only-for-dynamic-segments#answers-header; i think the setupController should be called.

Comment: your twiddle is not updated

Comment: sorry, i am not an expert on twiddle.  What do you mean when you say it is not updated?

Comment: When I click on the twiddle link you provided. its showing default files alone. its not containing your changes....You need to click on File menu -> Save to github gist and then click share twiddle link. Update that link in the question

Comment: How do I update it.  Presently if I got to /dummy/1 in the output panel I see two links.

Comment: You please  click the link you provided in the Question ? see is it contianing `/dummy/1` route stuff code ?

Comment: When you call transitionTo by providing the model object, then model hook will not be called likewise setupController hook also will not be called.

Comment: I updated the twiddle

Comment: @kumkanillam I updated the twiddle.  I am able to get the model to be called, but not the setupController.  I need the setupController to be called since I am setting values for the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be some change in model hook return data, if it's not same then it's not calling the setupController hook. So if you change model hook to return new different data for every dynamic segment then setupController hook is called.
For testing purpose, you can include the below code,

```
model(params){
    console.log('hello1 ',params);
    return new Date();
  },
```

or include the below code,

```
model(params){
    console.log('hello1 ',params);
    return 'hi'+params.dummy_id;
  },
```

Comment: I haven't noticed this behavior and I am not sure about current behavior is intended or not.

Comment: I will give you the answer, since you did answer my question.  However, I see that I did not word my question right or give the best twiddle example.  I really wanted to force the my route to reload the same model.  That model will change.  But it will have the same ember data id.  That is what was making my setupController not fire.  So I made some hack to change the id of the model coming back from the server.  Thanks for your help.